# Using code to check if IE add on is enabled in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, c#-3.0

I want to check if the Internet Explorer Rendering engine is turned on in Mozilla browser, then I hide some control in my code.
If the browser itself is Internet Explorer, then I want to show control.

So The question is how to I detect and differentiate between Internet Explorer Rendering engine is tured on in Mozilla browser and Internet Explorer browser?

User Agent of navigation object for mozilla browser with IE turn on is:

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

User Agent of navigation object for IE browser:

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

Comment: Why would you waste your time on this? If someone wants FF to pretend it's IE, let them. If your site malrenders for them, that's their own problem. Writing special code to detect whether X is Y, rather than whether the functionality you need is supported by using feature detections, is going to take away time that you could spend on making the product better on standard browser setups. If someone installs a plugin that changes the browser behaviour, that's their doing, trying to work around that is usually a waste of time, and also being a bit of a jerk =)